# Counting word matches

Tags: google-apps-script

This has been driving me crazy - it seems it should be simple, but I can't find how to get this to work.

In Apps Script, I have a string (taken from a cell formula) and want to count how many times a certain word or phrase appears.  I thought match should do it, but I can't get it to work with a variable.  Only with typing it directly.  Is there a way to do this using a variable?

I have had a look at regexp, but there is not much on the Google pages.  That may be my best option though I don't understand it.

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "'=IFERROR(IF('Train Station'!D154 ='A','A: Good - Performing well',
                       IF('Train Station'!D154='B','B: OK',
                       IF('Train Station'!D154='C','C: Do Better',
                       IF('Train Station'!D154='D','D: Give Up')))),'')'";
  // var searchfor = '/'+'Train'+'/g';
  // var regex = new RegExp(searchfor)
  // var answer = RegExp(searchfor,str). //str.match(/+searchfor+/g).length;
  var answer = str.match(/Train/g).length
Logger.log(answer)
}
```

### EDIT / UPDATE

Getting closer.  RegExp seems to be what I need (without all the /s\g*!!? stuff I was worried about).  Now I just need to manage what happens withe the error : Cannot read property 'length' of null.

```
var searchfor = 'Train';
  var regex = str.match(new RegExp(searchfor, "g")).length
Logger.log(regex)
```

I was going to progress this project using `If regex == 4 then`  but the nulls are winning that battle.  For now.

### SUCCESS!!

```
var regex = (str.match(new RegExp(searchfor, "g"))||[]).length
```

I'm not going to even think how many hours I spent on this.  Hopefully someone will find this helpful one day.

`str` is the string to look at, `searchfor` is the text to find, the `"g"` flag (global) and `||[]` returns 0 if the result is null.

Thanks to all who looked at this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "'=IFERROR(IF('Train Station'!D154 ='A','A: Good - Performing well',
                       IF('Train Station'!D154='B','B: OK',
                       IF('Train Station'!D154='C','C: Do Better',
                       IF('Train Station'!D154='D','D: Give Up')))),'')'";
  var searchfor = 'Train';
  var regex = (str.match(new RegExp(searchfor, "g"))||[]).length;
  Logger.log(regex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function myFunction() {
  var str = "'=IFERROR(IF('Train Station'!D154 ='A','A: Good - Performing well'IF('Train Station'!D154='B','B: OK',IF('Train Station'!D154='C','C: Do Better',IF('Train Station'!D154='D','D: Give Up'),'')'";
  // var searchfor = '/'+'Train'+'/g';
  // var regex = new RegExp(searchfor)
  // var answer = RegExp(searchfor,str). //str.match(/+searchfor+/g).length;
  var answer = str.match(/Train/g).length
Logger.log(answer)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cooper.  I put the formula string like that so it was easier to read, but appreciate the reply.  I am trying to count the number of matches in the string if 'Train' was the value of the variable 'searchfor'.  I was showing the only way I could get match to work, but need to be able to utilise a variable.